# Android SDK Twilio Programmable Voice call immediately completes

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api

I am using the new **Android SDK** and in backend **NodeJS**. If i try to generate token using node then it gives generic error. But if i use **PHP** to generate token then this token works but if I try to call, Call immediately completes.

Comment: show us the code with relevant config and logs etc.

Comment: Hi, I'm a developer evangelist for Twilio. Would love to help, but I'd really need to see your code, both the Node and PHP for generating a token and the TwiML you are using to make the call.